# how to disable the automatic switch to the start date calendar

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

After selecting the date range picker, it switches to the start point. I want it to stay on the end date calendar after selecting the year 2022. I want to disable the automatic switch to the start date calendar

I want to disable the automatic switch to the start date calendar

Comment: need details and clarity, which data picker you are using what have you tried every datails

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+daterangepicker+start+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.